# How do i upload external files onto my server using AD credentials?

Tags: file, upload, authentication

i want some of my users to be able to go home and upload their files from Home PC's by going to say www.mydomain.com/upload

it will ask for their windows username and password then take those files and upload them to their re-directed folder on the fileserver...

im guessing SSL encryption is a start (or probably my last step). Can i do a VB script server ened and a runas - Copy?

Answer (score 0):

Uh... you've got the right idea, but step back a moment.

There are two main options:
* WebDAV - Anyone with a modern OS can configure "Web Folders". Windows will present the network location as a filesystem folder where users can simply drag and drop files to upload them. This requires configuring IIS.
* A web-based file upload script - There are many of these around, however very few of these integrate authentication with IIS and support Kerberos. You do not need TLS/SSL for Windows Authentication or Kerberos, but it might be a good idea anyway. You may need to write your own if you can't find what you want, however VBScript is not appropriate as it has no built-in support for Identity Impersonation or handling file uploads with ease (it is possible, but not very easy). You're better off using PHP or ASP.NET

HTH.